# Spinner in iOS, like in Android

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am very first time developing the Spinner in iOS.

I searched a lot for default Spinner view in iOS, but failed.
What I get is, two ways to design spinner like view in iOS.

1. UIPickerview
2. Custom TableView which will be displayed on Click of DownArrow Button

I found the tutorial for `UIPickerview`.
But There are some OS orientation for this,
Means I want the `UIPickerview` in different Look & feel with selection style, also Scrolling of picker is not as I want.
So I was thinking to go for second options.

But Is there any other superior way to achieve this task,
As I think the second option is GOOD, but NOT BEST.

What I want is like the image below, its from Android, 
I want to go for the same in iOS.

Thanks for help..

[image]

Comment: What is the problem of using a custom `UITableView`? Why don't you use it?

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate android instead of using an iOS style approach?

Comment: Hi @Trick, I am already having UITableView in which my header of table contains the Question for match the following and in cellForRowAtIndexpath I wan this Spinner
so UITableView on UITableView is quite confusing, and causing difficulties in binding.

Comment: Hi @Wain, I don't need look and feel, but working. As I want to show this spinner in UITablview cellforRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking is [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nidropdown)

But I use [RMPickerViewController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rmpickerviewcontroller--2) which is more powerfull.

Comment: Thanks for this. it helps.
I did little modification.
The code above shows the UIButton added on View.
So that the did select method place the selection text on UIbutton.
I have added the UIButton on UITableview cell, as my requirement.
but Problem is that Whenever drop down is shown and I select one option I am able to select the first one only, as rest my options are going below the cell boundary. I don't want to add drop down table on UIView. what the solution to overcome this. so that I can select any option which will reflect button on UITableViewCell.